# Android how to manage ad version and ad-free version

Tags: android

I developed an Android app. I want to release two versions of the app, an ad version and an ad-free version. If someone wants to purchase the ad-free version from the ad version, they simply click on some button and they can purchase the ad-free version. Please tell me how to manage both versions.

Comment: you are planning to release two different apps in market?

Comment: nops app is one but want to release the ads and ad free version if user download the add version which ll be free he can download it and if later on he want to change it to ad free version he can simply click in any settings  of ads version and ad free version automatically downloaded and replace with ads free version

Comment: I'd say that the second app should just be a "plugin" which sets a unique code to the database of the app with ads. Then, when opening this app again, check the unique code with a webservice and if accepted, disable adds by removing the view, or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use two different applications with different packages, as two apps cannot be released to play store with same package name, the pro version package can ends with "pro", then both the apps can be released to play store. Free app contains ad code and a link to play store for ad free version in menu like get pro version, when that is clicked user can download the pro app which doesn't have ads code.

Comment: yes this can be happen but i have another way can u help me in this way which way I should use and which one is better first one is your and second one is in the link by use of application unlocker kindly let me know 
[https://github.com/marvinlabs/android-unlocker-library#implement-the-apps-common-library-project]

Answer (score 1):

I was just going thru and I believe I came up with a solution programmatically instead of building two app versions.

Let's suppose you are working with AdMob. Add the code in the layout xml

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
```

Then on your Activity initialize the AdMob

```
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus 
         initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
```

And so when you gonna call to load adView make a condition. Connect to your server with a database where you can post with ads or no ads for the specific user.

```
Boolean WithAds;
String url = "https://yourdomain.com/getuserinfos.php";

Ion.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .setBodyParameter("UserX", "ads")
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                       WithAds = result.get("ads").getAsBoolean();
                    }
                });

if (WithAds == true) {
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
} else {//Do nothing}
```

If you don't call the request you won't have ads on your app!